# How to have a jquery toggle hide/show functionality that acts as multiple filtering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my page I have 3 text that act as filters that show/hide their respective classes.

1. All items
2. Items A
3. Items B

For example, when "all items" is clicked, all divs that have the class `items` are hidden, and a strikethrough line is showing over the "All items" text.

The same goes for the other 2 options.

The logical error that I am facing is when the 3 are combining, especially the "All items" with another option.

For example, If "All items" is clicked, and then "Items A", the "items A" will appear, but the strikethrough on "All items" remains.

You can see my code below.

How can I fix this "logical" errors and have a good filtering functionality?

```js
$(".itemA").click(function() {
    $(".itemA-item").toggle(800);
    $(".itemA").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
});
$(".itemB").click(function() {
    $(".itemB-item").toggle(800);
    $(".itemB").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
});
$(".all-items").click(function() {
    $(".items").toggle(800);
    $(".all-items").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
});
```

```css
.striketrough-line {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:30%;float:left;">
<h3>
filters
</h3>
<p class="all-items">
all items
</p>
<p class="itemA">
items A
</p>
<p class="itemB">
items B
</p>
</div>

<div style="width:69%;float:left">
<h3>
the items
</h3>
<div class="items itemA-item">
    <p>itemA 1</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="items itemB-item">
    <p>itemB 2</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="items itemA-item">
    <p>itemA 3</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="items itemB-item">
    <p>itemB 4</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and clean solution would be to contain all your items within `<div class="items">` instead of applying the `items` class individually to each item. That way, when toggling on or off one of the specific item groups, if the parent element is not visible (by disabling all items), its children won't be either.

Here's the modified version:

```js
$(".itemA").click(function() {
    $(".itemA-item").toggle(800);
    $(".itemA").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
});
$(".itemB").click(function() {
    $(".itemB-item").toggle(800);
    $(".itemB").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
});
$(".all-items").click(function() {
    $(".items").toggle(800);
    $(".all-items").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
});
```

```css
.striketrough-line {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:30%;float:left;">
    <h3>filters</h3>
    <p class="all-items">all items</p>
    <p class="itemA">items A</p>
    <p class="itemB">items B</p>
</div>

<div style="width:69%;float:left">
    <h3>the items</h3>
    <div class="items">
        <div class="itemA-item">
            <p>itemA 1</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="itemB-item">
            <p>itemB 2</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="itemA-item">
            <p>itemA 3</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="itemB-item">
            <p>itemB 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately this can not be a solution because is not scalable. there is a possibility of "objects" along with "items" ordered randomly. also it does not answer the strikethrough problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mechanism to check if there is a strikethrough at all. If true then it shall seize the functionality of itemA & itemB.

You can update your JS with this, and check:

```
var st_all = false;
$(".itemA").click(function() {
    if(!st_all)
    {
        $(".itemA-item").toggle(800);
        $(".itemA").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
    }
});
$(".itemB").click(function() {
    if(!st_all)
    {
        $(".itemB-item").toggle(800);
        $(".itemB").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
    }
});
$(".all-items").click(function() {
    $(".items").toggle(800);
    $(".all-items").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
    st_all = !st_all; //toggle st_all
    $(".itemA").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
    $(".itemB").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
});
```

**Update:** You can use a forcing mechanism to force the strike to all the items, if "all items" is clicked. Here's the code, you can give a shot to:

```
var st_all = false, force_st_all = false;
$(".itemA").click(function() {
    if(!st_all)
    {
        $(".itemA-item").toggle(800);
        $(".itemA").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
        force_st_all = true;
    }
});
$(".itemB").click(function() {
    if(!st_all)
    {
        $(".itemB-item").toggle(800);
        $(".itemB").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
        force_st_all = true;
    }
});
$(".all-items").click(function() {
    st_all = !st_all; //toggle st_all
    if (force_st_all) {
      $(".items").hide(800);
      $(".all-items").addClass("striketrough-line");
      $(".itemA").addClass("striketrough-line");
      $(".itemB").addClass("striketrough-line");
      force_st_all = !force_st_all;
    }
    else {
      $(".items").toggle(800);
      $(".all-items").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
      $(".itemA").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
      $(".itemB").toggleClass("striketrough-line");
    }
});
```

Live link: http://jsfiddle.net/fyagLwxq/

Comment: Hi, this is a great start. How can I handle the scenario: clicks "items A" and then clicks "all items" ? because in that case "items A" will show. here is a live example http://jsfiddle.net/7sdzbj9w/

Comment: @EnexoOnoma you may want to create a strike forcing mechanism, have a look at my updated answer and let me if it solve your purpose.